# Crypto++ AES crashing in release mode using VS2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, crypto++

I have the following code. A very simple example of encryption and decryption of string "abcd". I've tried it with sample from Crypto++ (https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC_mode) and it produces the same exception.

```
AutoSeededRandomPool rand;

SecByteBlock key(nullptr, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
rand.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());

byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
rand.GenerateBlock(iv, AES::BLOCKSIZE);

std::string encryptedData;
CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption cbcEncryption(key, key.size(), iv);

StringSource ss("abcd", true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcEncryption,
        new StringSink(encryptedData)
    )
);

std::string decryptedData;

CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption cbcDecryption(key, key.size(), iv);

StringSource ss2(encryptedData, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcDecryption,
        new StringSink(decryptedData)
    )
);
```

The problem is when I build in debug mode, it works fine but when I do it in release mode I get an exception from Crypto++ code ("StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found")

[image: Exception]

Comment: Is that Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.7)? If so, then it is a compiler bug. Also see [Issue 649, Windows and incorrect results for AES when used on CPUs without AES-NI](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/649). Its a blocking bug at the moment. The only workaround I know (at the moment) is to disable optimizations for the source file. That is, add `#pragma optimize ("", off)` to `rijndael.cpp`.

Comment: I'm using the latest VS2017, which is 15.8.8

Comment: The VS2017  global optimization issue is affecting our ChaCha AVX2 implementation, too. We had to disable global optimizations on the AVX2 source file, and not the base file like in your bug. Also see [Commit 092309b26687](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/092309b26687).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is when I build in debug mode, it works fine but when I do it in release mode I get an exception from Crypto++ code ("StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found") ...

It appears to be a compiler issue related to global optimizations. Our workaround was to disable global optimizations for the source file `rijndael.cpp`.

In `rijndael.cpp` you can add the following around the top of the file to avoid the issue:

```cxx
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1910)
# pragma optimize("", off)
# pragma optimize("ts", on)
#endif
```

You can reproduce the issue with the following in `rijndael.cpp`:

```cxx
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1910)
# pragma optimize("", off)
# pragma optimize("g", on)
#endif
```

Also see [Commit f57df06c5e6d](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/f57df06c5e6d) and [`pragma optimize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx) on MSDN.

---

If your machine has AES-NI but you want to reproduce the issue, then  comment-out the code that assigns `g_hasAESNI` in `cpu.cpp`. `g_hasAESNI` will retain the default value of `false`.

```diff
--- a/cpu.cpp
+++ b/cpu.cpp
@@ -242,7 +242,7 @@ void DetectX86Features()
        g_hasSSSE3 = g_hasSSE2 && ((cpuid1[2] & (1<< 9)) != 0);
        g_hasSSE41 = g_hasSSE2 && ((cpuid1[2] & (1<<19)) != 0);
        g_hasSSE42 = g_hasSSE2 && ((cpuid1[2] & (1<<20)) != 0);
-       g_hasAESNI = g_hasSSE2 && ((cpuid1[2] & (1<<25)) != 0);
+       //g_hasAESNI = g_hasSSE2 && ((cpuid1[2] & (1<<25)) != 0);
        g_hasCLMUL = g_hasSSE2 && ((cpuid1[2] & (1<< 1)) != 0);
```